# ng-repeat on directive in parent view or inside template of directive itself

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

what is the main difference when i put ng-repeat on the directive element inside the view.

```
...
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in items"></div>
...
```

or when i put it inside of my directive template?

```
...
scope { myItems: "=" },
template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="items in myItems">{{ item.name }}</li></ul>,
...
```

The only thing i can tell is that putting the ng-repeat inside of my view takes a few milliseconds more than putting it inside of my template.

Answer (score 0):

The end result should be the same, but the difference is that when `ng-repeat` is outside your directive, will compile at every iteration thus taking longer to render.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer! So if i understand this right, `ng-repeat` on the directive itself is used in example when you need N times a `controller` or a `link`?

Comment: Yes and no. If you use your directive once then the `ng-repeat` should be done inside of the directives template. If your directive is used multiple times then the `ng-repeat` should stay outside. The second option as already explain would take more to compile. Anyway it depends on the use cases.